# Dot product equality of three different vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given three vectors $A$, $B$ and $C$ of n dimension. Also $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_i$ are complex non zero values.

Can $A \cdot B$ = $C \cdot B$ and $A \neq C$ ?

On others words can $(A-C) \cdot B = 0$, being $ A \neq C $ ?

If this is answered somewhere or is too silly, please, point me out the reference since I wasn't able to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I made a typo on the first equation.

Comment: Yes. For example, if you take n = 3 (or more) and let A, B and C be the basis vectors.

Comment: What are $a_i$, $b_i$, etc. and how are they related to the vectors? "*Can $A \cdot B = C \cdot B$ and $A \neq B$?*" Sure, if $A = C$ for example.

Comment: @QuestionAsker True. Thanks! However, please, consider them non orthogonal vectors.

Comment: @null . $a_i$ is the i component of vector $A$ and so on.

I made a mistake on the referred equation. The restraint is $A \neq C$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An example:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} = 0$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} = 0$$

Therefore the answer is yes.

---

What you probably want to know is if you can solve equations involving dot products like:

$$\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{a} = b$$

where $\mathbf{x}$ is an unknown vector, $\mathbf{a}$ is a known vector,  and $b$ is a constant.

Eg. $$\mathbf{x}.\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\3 \end{pmatrix} = 2$$

With an operation like multiplication, you can find a unique solution for equations in that form. For example, $3x = 5$ has a unique solution for $x$.

This isn't necessarily true for dot products. In fact, if $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ are 3 dimensional vectors, then there are a whole plane of solutions for $\mathbf{x}$ which is why that is one of the standard notations for the equation of a plane.

Vector equation of a plane in 3 dimensions:

$$\mathbf{r}.\mathbf{n} = D$$

where $\mathbf{r}$ is a variable vector, $\mathbf{n}$ is a constant vector and $D$ is a constant.

Comment: Insightful comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
$$(A-C)\cdot B = 0$$
Just means that $A-C$ and $B$ are orthogonal ("perpendicular"), which can definitely happen. For instance, let $A = [2,2,1]$, $C = [1,1,3]$, and $B = [1,1,1]$.

Comment: Nice, simple and direct example! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any vector $\mathbf{D}$,
$$\mathbf{C} =
\mathbf{A\times D}+\frac{(\mathbf{A\cdot B})\mathbf{A}}{A^2}
\implies \mathbf{A\cdot C} = \mathbf{A\cdot B}$$